# Import flowtype disjoint union?

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

Using flowtype on a current react / redux project.
I define in my actions.js file a disjoint union type:

```js
export type ArticleAction =
   { type: 'ARTICLE_SET_EDITION' }
  | { type: 'ARTICLE_BLABLA', blip: string };
```

And then in my reducer I have

```js
import type { ArticleAction } from './actions';

[...]
 
const articlesReducer = (state: any = initialState, action: ArticleAction): any => {
  if (action.type === 'ARTICLE_BLABLA') {
    const test = action.blip.shoups;
    return test;
  }
 }
```

Flow does not detect a problem.

But! if I declare ArticleAction directly in reducer.js, it does recognize that action.blip.shoups is invalid because blip is a string.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong ?
thx

Comment: Do you have `// @flow` in actions.js?

Comment: yes I do have // @flow in both of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL;DR** Flow doesn't error in situations like this today, but most likely will in the future.

This doesn't have anything to do with the import/exports or even the union type, you could simplify it all the way down to this:

```
function method(val: 'foo') {
  if (val === 'bar') {
    // unreachable...
  }
}
```

Flow can see that it is a impossible refinement and could know that the inner code is unreachable. However, Flow does not error in unreachable scenarios. Today it simply marks the value of `val` as an "empty" type in that code path and moves on.

We have started to lay the groundwork for this **reachability** analysis and will use it to create errors in future versions of Flow.

We can also use reachability analysis to test **exhaustiveness**, i.e.:

```
function method(val: 'foo' | 'bar') {
  if (val === 'foo') {
    // ...
  } else if (val === 'bar') {
    // ...
  } else {
    // possibilities of val have been exhausted, this is unreachable...
  }
}
```

These are common requests and we are working on them.